# How to set Culture name kinect SDK

Tags: grammar, speech-recognition, kinect-sdk

i have an application in C# and i use a Kinect sensor for speech recognition.

It is possible to set the Culture in it-IT??

I think the problem is in the method GetKinectRecognizer() becouse in this method i set the property for the Speech Recognition.

Now i have this method

```
//riconoscimento vocale
    private SpeechRecognitionEngine RiconoscimentoVocale()
{
    RecognizerInfo ri = GetKinectRecognizer();

    SpeechRecognitionEngine sre;
    try
    {
        sre = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(ri.Id);
    }
    catch
    {
        this.Close();
        return null;
    }
    //vengono aggiunte la parole grammaticali da riconoscere
    var grammar = new Choices();
    grammar.Add("rosso");
    grammar.Add("aiuto");
    grammar.Add("caduto");

    //creo il vocabolario delle parole
    var vocabolario = new GrammarBuilder { Culture = ri.Culture };
    vocabolario.Append(grammar);

    // Create the actual Grammar instance, and then load it into the speech recognizer.
    var g = new Grammar(vocabolario);
    //carico la grammatica
    sre.LoadGrammar(g);
    //aggiungo l'evento per il riconoscimento delle parole
    sre.SpeechRecognized += this.RiconoscimentoParole;

    return sre;
}

private static RecognizerInfo GetKinectRecognizer()
{
    //Console.WriteLine("recognizer info ");
    Func<RecognizerInfo, bool> matchingFunc = r =>
    {

        Console.WriteLine("recognizer info " + r.Culture.Name);
        string value;
        r.AdditionalInfo.TryGetValue("Kinect", out value);
        return "True".Equals(value, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) && "en-US".Equals(r.Culture.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    };
    return SpeechRecognitionEngine.InstalledRecognizers().Where(matchingFunc).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Can we help me?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you've installed the [Italian language pack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34809), as that's a prerequisite.  Then, in your GetKinectRecognizer method, you need to change

```
return "True".Equals(value, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) && "en-US".Equals(r.Culture.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

to

```
return "True".Equals(value, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) && "it-IT".Equals(r.Culture.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

Also, your function seems very similar to the code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10613559/speech-recognition-on-kinect?rq=1), which had its own problems, so you may not be out of the woods yet.

But the general outline is there - you need to return the ID of an Italian recognizer (which you must install).